# onChange doesn't work with FromControl React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am having issues getting the `onChange` event from `FormControl` in React Bootstrap.

```
const textChangeHandler = (e) => {
   console.log(e);
};

<InputGroup size="sm" className="mt-2">
    <InputGroup.Prepend>
        <InputGroup.Text onChange={textChangeHandler}>
            #
        </InputGroup.Text>
    </InputGroup.Prepend>
    <FormControl />
</InputGroup>
```

When I type in the text field it doesn't log the changes in the console. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put `onChange` props to your `FormControl` component

```
<InputGroup size="sm" className="mt-2">
    <InputGroup.Prepend>
        <InputGroup.Text >
            #
        </InputGroup.Text>
    </InputGroup.Prepend>
    <FormControl onChange={textChangeHandler}/>
</InputGroup>
```

Comment: How do I log the text in the field using that? It works but it's returning an object

Comment: Try logging ```e.target.value```

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck!